# Overriding a framework gesture in AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, uigesturerecognizer

I want the ability to change how the playback controls are presented while using the new AVPlayerViewController in AVKit. Basically, I want to overide the single finger tap gesture to do something else, and replace that gesture with a double finger tap. I am subclassing AVPlayerViewController to add this functionality.

I can add the double finger tap easily by creating a new UITapGestureRecognizer, but doing so with a single tap does nothing, as the playback controls still appear and my custom gesture method is not called. I assume because the AVPlayerViewController has a gesture with priority that is called instead.

I setup the gestures like normal...

```
// singleFingerTap: will never fire...
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleFingerTap:)];
singleFingerTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
singleFingerTap.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

// doubleFingerTap: will work correctly...
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleFingerTap:)];
doubleFingerTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
doubleFingerTap.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleFingerTap];
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve this without accessing private properties? Is it even permitted? I know I can create my own view controller with an instance of AVPlayer and then create my own playback controls, but I'm hoping I can use the lightweight AVKit player here with a few simple modifications.

I've tried looping through the gestures in AVPlayerViewController's view and removing them, but the gestureRecognizers property was empty. Even if I could do this, I wouldn't know how to add back the gesture to display the playback controls on a double finger tap instead of the single finger tap.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated! Especially whether this is possible/allowed or not. Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**
I have found a way to explicitly unblock the player's private gesture that was blocking my own gesture.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    id firstGesture = gestureRecognizer;
    id secondGesture = otherGestureRecognizer;

    if ([firstGesture isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]] && [secondGesture isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = firstGesture;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *otherTapGesture = secondGesture;

        if (tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired == otherTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired && tapGesture.numberOfTouches == otherTapGesture.numberOfTouches) {
        // Disable the single tap that shows the playback controls...
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

This effectively prevents the playback controls from appearing on a tap, and my singleTapGesture: fires as expected. However, I now have the issue of getting the playback controls to appear on a different gesture. *Is it possible to reroute the private gesture, or simulate the private gesture programmatically?*

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check/modify the target/remove the default gesture recognizers first?

You can access them with the standard `UIView`'s `gestureRecognizers`.

---

The gestures recognizers may be buried inside a private subview.

Another solution would be to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` and add your gesture recognizers to the superview or to a "overlay" transparent view.

Comment: That's what I was hoping for, but after looking for the gesture recognizers with self.view.gestureRecognizers, the gestureRecognizers array is nil (self being the subclass of AVPlayerViewController). I'm looking to find out where I can get access to the gestureRecognizers, if I can at all, in the AVPlayerViewController class.

Comment: In response to your edit... I started to explore this, but then I began to realize some other issues I would run into. Mainly how I would go about bringing up the playback controls if I'm blocking gestures on the player view. This is the main issue, since Apple does not seem to allow toggling the player controls on AVPlayerViewController in a way other than a touch by the user.

I did however find a way of blocking the single touch gesture that was blocking my own method from firing, but now the issue is to have the ability to bring up the playback controls from somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe you have to think if having two actions triggered on single tap is a good idea, or if "diverting" the original behavior to another gesture or action would be ok for users.